# Cannot find data type time sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have problem error syntax with notice

> Cannot find data type time.

this my query SQL Server 2008 R2

```
CREATE TABLE test
  (
     ID             INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
     Emp_No         VARCHAR (255),
     AC_No          VARCHAR (255),
     No             VARCHAR (255),
     NAME           VARCHAR(255),
     Auto_Assign    VARCHAR(255),
     Date           DATETIME,
     Timetable      VARCHAR(255),
     on_duty        TIME,
     off_duty       TIME,
     clock_in       TIME,
     clock_out      TIME,
     Normal         INT,
     Realtime       INT,
     Late           INT,
     Early          INT,
     Absent         VARCHAR(255),
     OT_Time        TIME,
     Work_time      TIME,
     Departmen      VARCHAR(255),
     total_telat    INT,
     sakit          VARCHAR (255),
     ijin           VARCHAR (255),
     cuti           VARCHAR (255),
     alpha          VARCHAR (255),
     dinas_luar     VARCHAR (255),
     ket_dinas_luar VARCHAR(255),
     sts_tgl_merah  VARCHAR(255),
     telat_1_30min  INT,
     lembur_status  VARCHAR(255),
     lembur_time    INT
  );
```

[image]

Comment: Post the original code instead of image

Comment: Run `select compatibility_level from sys.databases where name ='myDB'` change `MyDB` on your actual database name.

Comment: eror sys.databases

Comment: Invalid object name 'sys.databases'

Comment: If you try something like `time(3)`?

Comment: Try wrapping the field called date in square brackets.

Comment: @P.Salmon - Not needed, `DATE` is not a **reserved** keyword

Comment: that no work to time(3)

Comment: @GAMEFORMEriskiNoeNoe "Invalid object name 'sys.databases' " it means that you have version/compatibility level prior to 2008

Comment: i try use manual change in design database there no time datatype. any update for 2008 to add time datatype?

Comment: try this, ALTER DATABASE dbname SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 105

Comment: @kushan Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: ALTER DATABASE dbname SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100

Comment: i try change compability lvl in option there only 2 type compabilty lvl 70 and 80.

Comment: Again check your sql server version

Comment: compabilty 80 means Sql server 2000

Comment: @ kushan that is 2008

Comment: try, select name, compatibility_level from sys.databases

Comment: @Kushan I think you have got SQL 2000, not 2008. What is the result of running `SELECT @@VERSION`?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM)

Comment: @kushan yea that show 2000 , that make me confused i instal sql server 2008 client =,= and why db 2000 version instaled there.

Comment: @Kushan sorry I confused you with OP. Question should have been directed to OP

Comment: @GAMEFORMEriskiNoeNoe sounds like you have got SQL 2000 DB then. Therefore time type doesn't exist, you'll need to use datetime instead. Or install SQL 2008.

Comment: yea let me try tomorrow today office is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server 2000 doesn't support `time` data type.

Use `datetime` data type